# Micronaut resolves view before redirecting

Tags: micronaut

I have following route methods.

```
@View(create-user) @Get(/create) public HttpResponse newUser(...)
@View(create-user) @Post(/create) public HttpResponse newUserSubmitted(...)
```

When form is submitted request goes to `newUserSubmitted`. If there is an error with any of the fields the same view is displayed with error message and retaining user input provided through `formData` object.
When submission is successful, there is a redirect to another page.

```
if (success) {
  return HttpResponse.redirect(new URI("/otherPage")
} else {
  return HttpResponse.ok(CollectionUtils.mapOf("data", formData, "error", "Validation error"));
}
```

There seems to be an issue where on success, before redirect happens, template is rendered but because `formData` is not available to the template, it errors out with `Exception processing template "create-user" ...`

Expected behavior would be to skip template rendering when redirect headers are present.
Micronaut 3.9.4